# Drupal messages being lost on form redirect

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to print a message when a user registers. I created a form submit handler which calls drupal_set_message and returns '/'. I put a watchdog message in my submit handler to ensure it was being called, and it is.

After the redirect I'm getting no messages though. My debugging dpms from devel don't work, my drupal_set_message doesn't work, etc. The template that's being used definitely is printing $messages.

I checked out the very similar question but it doesn't seem to apply. My user 0 exists and it's also quite an old answer.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't call `drupal_goto` in form API! `$form_state['redirect'] = 'my/new/path`

Comment: I'm not calling drupal_goto.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing hook_form_alter() to add a custom submit handler. Be sure to clear cache so your hook gets detected.

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add a custom submit handler to the user register form
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_reg_handler';
}

function mymodule_custom_reg_handler(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Hi mom!');
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I have, which is why I'm so confused by drupal not printing the message. :\

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of is that messages are getting cleared with something like: `drupal_get_messages(NULL, TRUE)` somewhere else in the code.